# FIltering ADC input

Tags: adc, analog, filtering

I would like to filter signal on ADC input. My question is if I can add before input ordinary RC filter. I suppose that this is not good idea. I have to limit number of operational amplifiers on the board so it can't be isolated by buffer amplifier.

If resistance is too big the internal (S&H) capacitor will not fully recharge. Capacitor from RC filter will be parallel with capacitor from S&H and it will change the capacitance of sampling capacitor? Am I right or not ?

cheers

Comment: Usually, ADC manufacturers suggest a typical interface connection in the datasheets, or related application notes.

Comment: You are probably not right.  There is a lot of supposition here.  What a2d are you talking about, what clock frequency, and what single frequencies do you want to pass?

Comment: If you have enough frequency 'space' between signal and sampling rate, an R/C can surely be used. For the R, look into the datasheet to find the max. impedance the ADC can accept on its input and/or make sure that the C is much bigger than the S&H capacitor (which may be some pF only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not sampling, the filter capacitor will charge to the filtered vin value.  Now when you sample, charge will move from the filter cap to the hold cap.  The resistor is there but doesn't have much to do with it.  If the filter cap is large compared to the hold capacitor, then the voltage will change very little and the hold capacitor will  charge very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a C to ground at the input of a sampling converter is a good idea, as it provides a reservoir for the charge needed by the converter. Check the data sheet for what value capacitors are OK. Once the C is providing the charge, a series R is usually OK. Again check the converter data sheet for recommendations on the value of the R.

Comment: I was trying to find this data in datasheet but I found only information how to calculate protection resistor. Maybe I don't understand this datasheet, could you tell me which data  indicates to this? MAX11046 [link]https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX11044-MAX11056.pdf

Comment: @e2p That is a tame converter, the inputs are easy to drive. The analogue inputs go to T/H amplifiers, not directly to naked ADCs. My comments were addressed to the latter. The specified input capacitance 15pF is very low, and the 1uA input leakage current is the only limitation on the size of the R. You have no worries.

Answer (score 1):

A simple RC filter will get the job done but you'll be sacrificing a lot of bandwidth. The maximum frequency you can sample is 1/2 sampling frequency so with 48kHz sampling frequency you'd be limited to 24kHz or less. To achieve that you actually need to set filtering corner frequency at a lower frequency to have adequate attenuation at the 1/2 sample frequency.

You only get -20dB/decade of attenuation with RC filter so to get -20dB attenuation at that 24kHz frequency, your corner frequency should be 2.4kHz so you're filtering out quite a lot.

You'd really do better with 2nd or 3rd order opamp filter which requires you to use one of your opamps. See some examples here: http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4363970/Design-second-and-third-order-Sallen-Key-filters-with-one-op-amp

Here's a neat tool for designing the 3rd order sallen key filter. Just give it the cherbychew corner frequency and off you go. You probably want to define C1=C2 based on some convenient component value. 
http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/Sallen3tool.php

With regards to the capacitor, what will actually happen (with some ADC types e.g. sample and hold input stage) is that the charge from the external capacitance transfers to the internal capacitance. So you in fact want to have enough capacitance to keep this glitch < 1/2 ADC unit.

Comment: kS/s not kbit/s but +1 for reminding about aliasing filters.

Comment: Thanks Barleyman, unfortunatelly as I wrote I coulnd't use more opamps and build active filter. Sacrificing bandwidth is not a problem (sampling frequency is 250 kS/s and signal is maximum 15kHz )

Comment: @user128885 I usually have some extras since they come in pairs.. There's even a song about how to connect your unused opamps.

Comment: @user128885 That frequency information should go into the original question!

Comment: @user128885 If your sample frequency is 250kHz, you need to filter >125kHz, meaning you should have your corner frequency @ 12.5kHz which is going to eat at your signal. -3dB at corner frequency means halving the signal!

Comment: @JimmyB my question is not about filtering frequency. I am interested how resistance and capacitance connected to the ADC inputs cooperate with internal capacitor

Comment: @e2p As pointed out a couple of times, there's a charge transfer going on so you want adequate capacitor size. Maxim doesn't actually tell you what's the size of the SAH sample capacitor but we can presume it's smaller than the 15pF input capacitance. Going by healthy three orders of magnitude, with 15nF you should see (almost) no sampling glitch. If you have a decent oscilloscope, use small ~22pF RC filter cap and you should see the sampling glitch.

Comment: @Barleyman, sorry for digging up this old post but i have a question regarding your answer. Why do you need to have a -20dB at attenuation at half of the sampling frequency, can it be lower ?

Comment: @rdevices -20dB means the signal is at 1/10th of the original amplitude, it's not really all that much suppression. There are stereos with -20dB "mute" button and you can still clearly hear the music playing if it was on a normal level to start. What's acceptable depends on your application but 10% noise (via aliasing) is usually not that great. You'd probably want -30dB or -40dB for a good result. You can build a 3rd order low-pass filter with one opamp and you could get -39dB attenuation by setting the corner frequency to 1/4th of the stop frequency or -21dB with 1/2.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, we need to talk about *impedance*.

The ADC will have specified a certain *maximum* impedance for its input signal. That number already factors in the S&H capacitor, so in the simple case you have just an R/C of the signal impedance/line resistance and the S&H C. You are allowed to increase the signal's impedance up to the maximum, so you can just add a resistor in line to get close to that value.

Notice that a C to ground *decreases* the impedance, so it only makes sense if your signal impedance (after the R) is bigger than allowed. If it is, then you need to select (for a given R) a C to get to within the allowed impedance range *for the frequency* of the signal.

Hence, the numbers for R and C to use can be figured out from the required impedance of the ADC and the signal's frequency alone.